# Mysql : dump database along data

Tags: mysql, sql, dump

I want to dump my database along the table schema and the table data also using the unix command line .

I used .

```
mysqldump -d -u root  -p frontend > frontend.sql
```

But above command is dumping only schema not the data from the database .

Please help me out how can i dump the database along the data also.

Comment: What you want is `mysqldump`.

Comment: -d from man mysql dump `Do not write any table row information (that is, do not dump table contents). This is useful if you want to dump only
           the CREATE TABLE statement for the table (for example, to create an empty copy of the table by loading the dump file).
`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
backup: # mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```

This will do,

If your requirement is to dump data alone then go for this,

To export to file (data only)

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p[pass] --no-create-db --no-create-info mydb > mydb.sql
```

Comment: @masterofdestiny can you try this and get back to me if you face any issues

Comment: if your database engine is InnoDB, you will prefer to use `--single-transaction` option. Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

Comment: I guess this method create sql with only create table statements without **create dataabse statement**.

Answer (score 21):

backup: #

```
mysqldump -u root -p[password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```

restore:#

```
mysql -u root -p[password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql
```

[ref:] http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/

Answer (score 14):

You just need to remove `-d` from your `mysqldump` command

Comment: I was struggling to find this answer which just worked.

Comment: That's the solution! +1

Answer (score 3):

mysqldump offers plenty of options to build a proper backup from your database:

```
mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]
mysqldump [options] --databases db_name ...
mysqldump [options] --all-databases
```

Here you can find more detail about how to mysqldump:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 1):

You're missing --no-data=False

e.g.

mysqldump -d -u root frontend --no-data=False -p > frontend.sql

Comment: Yeah that is the ideal answer. thank you

Answer (score 0):

To restore database from .sql dumpfile

> mysql -u [yourusername] -p [password] [nameofthedatabase] <
>   /pathtoyoursqldumpfile.sql

Use mysqldump to create backup from database.

> mysqldump -u [yourusername] -p [password] [nameofthedatabase] >
>   /pathtoyoursqldumpfile.sql

Answer (score -2):

I think the command you would need will be mysqldump. Try the following:

```
mysqldump -u root -p -h localhost frontend < frontend.sql
```

Comment: Why is `frontend.sql` directed to stdin?  Does `mysqldump` read from stdin?

Comment: please check updated i tried that but it is dumping only schema

Comment: the only bad thing with this answer is the direciton of the data redirection.. it should be ">", not "<".. > redirects the output from mysqldump into frontend.sql.. < READS the frontend.sql and redirects it to the stdin of mysqldump.. wich wil do nothing with it.