# mysqldump wont dump my data

Tags: mysql

here is the command I'm using:

```
mysqldump.exe -u root -d capstone -verbse --skip-quote-names > capstone.sql
```

and the output I get

```
mysqldump: Warning: Can't set SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE option ()
-- Skipping dump data for table 'users', --no-data was used
```

any ideas? if I dump to XML it works but the place I'm importing it to doesn't handle XML and my data ruins the CSV output somehow too.

Comment: What kind of operating system is your server running?

Comment: I just realized I'm an idiot. the -d flag is not used to define the database but to signal --no-data.

Comment: It happens sometimes...so solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql : dump database along data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022859/mysql-dump-database-along-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean to use either `-B` / `--databases` (which includes allows you to indicate multiple *databases* to dump instead of a database and tables) or no such argument at all.  I think you also mistyped `--verbose`.

Note that if you include `--databases` a `CREATE DATABASE` statement is also included.  This could be important depending up on how you intend to use the data.

Answer (score 3):

the `-d` option is alias of `--no-data`, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data

perhaps you intended to state "use database capstone" but in that case it wouldn't be `-d capstone`, the database name doesn't need any switch/option, just put it in there

```
shell> mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]
shell> mysqldump [options] --databases db_name ...
shell> mysqldump [options] --all-databases
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-syntax

Comment: This is the answer for those who have assumed postgres-like parameters. (Normally, `psql` uses `-d` to select a database: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html)