# SQL search all table all column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a value in my SQL database, but documentation doesn't tell in which table or which column is the value.

All information I have is the value "use_config_gift", and I wanna look in all table of the database for finding the text.

Is this possible ? I'm using Mysql on a terminal, and the db is a little big (560+ tables).

Anyone got an idea please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/mysql-search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-from-a-database

Comment: I try using this post, and getting information in information_schema table help me to find all table name, but I can't use information exept looking in all table one by one =/

Comment: Yep, I try all solution, but using Mysql and can't execute a php file (not installed, can't install it)

Comment: If total database size is not that big then you can do a [mysqldump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022859/mysql-dump-database-along-data) and search for your value into the resulting file.

Comment: Database take more than 50Go, in 560 table, so this solution can't work >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this script:

http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/find-in-all-databases-tables.sql_.txt

This script was written to search in all dbs but you can replace:

WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema','test','mysql');

with:

WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('YOUR_DB_NAME');

The source :

http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/search-through-all-databases-tables-columns-in-mysql

Bye!

Comment: I presume that I have to change "WHERE `', column_name,'` REGEXP "',in_search,'"'", the ',in_search,', by 'use_config_gift' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use full text search functions in MYSQL

Kindly visit the link below for references :

[Full text search MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: Thanks, but it can also be another think that plan text (varchar for example, so this solution doesn't work